# Can I stop specific 'devices' from showing up in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus seems to list all partitions under "devices".

On my system, this includes a Windows 7 partition and a "System Reserved" partition created by Windows.

I would prefer to hide those two partitions. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way that used to work was manually creating mount points in `/etc/fstab` and mounting them in `/mnt` (or anywhere else but not in `/media/`). If they're already mounted somewhere, Nautilus shouldn't bother you with the drives.

If you also add `noauto` to the mount option for these partitions, it won't mount it on boot either, saving a bit of time.